# Changing the size of an image used in a hyperlink XHTML

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, styles

In an assignment i have to make a website with hyperlinks to external websites, the website has the styles in the head not on a separate css. I have a piece of of code that sets all the image size but the ones in the in the hyper links. how would i be able to change the size without having to change it for each individual hyperlink.

example of my hyperlink and my style for images

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0144117/>http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Boondock-Saints-the-boondock-saints-653316_1600_1200.jpg alt=boondock saints poster> 
img {width:178px;height:270px }

Answer (score -1):

You have got it completely wrong.

First of all you should know how to construct a correct a tag, which is this way:

```
<a href="< your link here >" title="some text here" target="">Click me</a>
```

and this is the time when you want to make an image cliccable:

```
<a href="< your link here >" title="some text here" target=""><img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg" alt="some image short description here" class="image" /></a>
```

Now if you want to style the image (for example to give this image a set width & height) ... you use css (its better not to use inline-css just for the sake of keeping the code clean).

Example of css:

```
.image { width: 100px; height: auto; }
```

You can even do a little hover effect just like this:

```
.image:hover { opacity: 0.8; }
```

Example is on cssdeck:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/kj7lqowb

Hope it helps to clarify what you are doing wrong.